# Strange shading on faces in Blender 2.8?

Tags: faces

I'm working on a character head in Blender 2.8 (which I'm new to, so bear with me), and the shading on the faces is very odd around the bridge of the nose, and the bottom of the eye on the left.  It looks like there's overlapping faces or something, but there isn't as far as I can tell, and that shading is showing up in a render as well.  There are no duplicate vertices and all the normals are going in the right direction.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Model: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "odd shading" is shadow from your lamp.

[image]

Try moving your lamp lower and forward some.

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was that simple.... Thanks for your help!