# Strange shading on flat surface

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, shaders, unity

I am trying to model a snooker table for an Unity game and I have an issue with strange shadows on the cushion:
[image]

This is how I modeled the curved edge:
[image]

It's not an Unity issue because if I choose smooth shading on Blender, I get some strange behavior too:
[image]

I tried to recalculate the normals and I also checked if the top vertices are on the same plane and they are. Am I modeling it wrong?

[image]

Comment: perhaps share this part of your object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I added it at the bottom of the post

Comment: This looks a little like the shading problem here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126657/strange-shading-on-faces-in-blender-2-8/126664#126664  Try moving your lamp about or disable Shadow in the Light menu.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog I have no lights in the blender file. Moreover, the strange shading on my model occurs on a flat surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I fixed it. I am still learning so I am not sure what fixed it but I:
 1. applied the modifiers
 2. removed UV Maps on all meshes on Object Data
 3. exported to Unity
 4. checked Generate Lightmap UVs box in asset imported in Unity

I think it was an issue with UV Maps.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you get this issue with orphaned vertices, which can be fixed with Merge By Distance option. And sometimes it needs to be UV reunwrapped, as I think you have discovered.